# Reading Linux via Windows [C program]

Tags: c, linux

My teacher asked my class to make a c program to read data on my linux partition via a c program in windows .

As such , after a good amount of research , i have been unsuccessful to find even the smallest hint as to how . 
I realize the eof is different , but changing that allows me to read a file created in linux , not directly access the linux partition itself .

I was hoping that someone could please gimme a clue .

P.S I would really appreciate it if i was not given the complete code / info , i just wanna know where to start .

Comment: That's pretty hardcore, since you need to open the partition in RAW mode and parse the filesystem yourself (unless you are meant to use existing code)

Answer (score 2):

1. Can you read a "windows" file on "windows"? This is a good starting point along with manual pages for fopen etc.
2. EOF is the same everywhere - it is the end of file. The library "stdio" treats it the same wherever. That is why it is called standard IO
3. Just mount the linux partition onto your windows machine. I think the lecturer was doing this to make sure you was awake during the course.